# Difference between live, look alive and heartbeat in SQL server cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql

What is the difference between is live, look alive and heartbeat in SQL server cluster?

All these are same or not?

If yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LooksAlive Check:
This check performs a basic verification that the SQL Server service is running on the hosted node which should be online on a given interval of time. The default time that has been set is 5 seconds.

In case the check fails, the cluster service performs another check which is very thororugh in nature called the IsAlive Check to verify the failure.
The LooksAlive check is also known as Basic resource health check in Windows Server 2008.

IsAlive check:
This process checks and verifies the cached result of the internal IsAlive process in the SQL Server resource DLL. The internal IsAlive process runs every 60 seconds and verifies if SQL server is online or not. The check uses `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` to verify the state of the SQL Server.

In case that the query fails, it runs an additional retry login to avoid failures. On the event of retry logic failure, the internal IsAlive process shuts down the SQL server service and a failover event is triggered. The IsAlive check is also known as the Thorough resource health check in Windows Server 2008.